# For a 64 bit OS, is memory leakage still relevant?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, gcc, x86-64

If you have a 64 bit OS, you have an address space of virtually unlimited size. So my question is, does on such systems freeing memory matters much? Even if you have limited RAM of say 4 GB, in a demand paging scheme (memory only brought in when touched), the little overhead you would get as compared to freeing memory, is a few extra page swaps I guess, as memory you will not touch for a long time, will automatically be swapped. Am I missing something here? Or is my argument valid?

Practically, if it is not a big performance hit, then I guess its a good thing for C/C++ programmers, as memory leakage would no more be an important issue to deal with!

Comment: Yes, the more memory you add, the less likely a memory leak is to crash the application, much less the entire machine. But that doesn't mean it's good practice to leak practice. Ask yourself what would happen if everyone started doing this and you'll see why. It's hard to see the purpose of this question.

Comment: How do you propose the OS will decide in advance which memory you are intending to send to purgatory and which memory is required for active service? It would have to ensure that active memory didn't find itself on any of the countless wasted pages you intend to create, lest it spend its time constantly swapping in page after page of predominantly dead data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> overhead ... is a few extra page swaps ... as memory ... will automatically be swapped

Automatically be swapped to where? The ether? Page files are finite, as is the storage they exist on.

Do you think it's a good idea never to free memory in a long running service application?

Answer (score 3):

I think the keyword here is "virtually" - the definition of which boils down to "not, in fact." You have a memory space that is not, in fact, unlimited. All that's really changed with the growing availability of memory is the scope of the application you can afford to be callous about memory management with.

Put another way, if you're writing "Hello World", then sure, you can leave your memory garbage in place. These days, you could *probably* get away with a small app that didn't manage its own memory. But if you write a device driver or a service daemon that's expected to run as long as the operating system does... well, I don't want to have to bring down a production machine once a week to manually clean up anybody else's memory leaks.

Comment: I think that many people here are misreading the question. He’s not suggesting that we nowadays have enough memory to not care about memory leaks. He’s considering a situation where the apps would not release memory *because* the leaked memory would eventually get paged out by system, thus freeing the RAM again. On a 32-bit system the process could easily run out of the address space, on 64-bit system the idea has some sort of sense.

Comment: @zoul Thus freeing RAM and taking up space in the page file. Which doesn't have space for an unlimited number of memory pages. So this post about the semantics of *virtual(ly)* doesn't seem misplaced to me.

Answer (score 2):

Is it not just best practice to cleanup memory allocated before.

If all programs stop to release memory block because of performance reasons, you will see what happens.

Yes, it matters much.

Comment: Yeah but I don't think you will have much performance hit, which is my question. It can also be good in practical situations, as memory leaks would no more be a big problem to deal with!

Comment: “See what happens” is not really an ideal answer, since the scenario is hard to reproduce. I’m sure the poster is interested in what exactly would happen and why.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: you will have the same performance hit as on a 32-bit system with.an equal amount of memory. Where do you believe the difference should arise from?

Comment: Groo, in 32 bit systems, you only have 4GB of address space, you cant go over that limit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the application. Some applications are allocating a big lot (e.g. several hundred megabytes per second). If you consider you'll never free that, but uses swap space, you'll fill a multi-gigabyte swap in a few hours.

See the huge literature about garbage collection, e.g. [the garbage collection handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) for a start.

The old Andrew Appel's paper [garbage collection can be faster than stack allocation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/45.ps) should give you interesting insights.

However, you could consider a garbage collector which leaks a little, then the leak rate would be only a few megabytes per minute (after GC), and the situation is different.

And when you consider only short lived applications, memory leak is indeed less important. But as soon as you have long-lasting server processes, you should care about memory, and never releasing (or reusing) it is a bad idea.

Comment: Your numbers are *slightly* overestimated. A program allocating 100 MB per second allocates about 350 GB in one hour - with 300 ("several hundred") MB/s and 3 hours ("a few hours"), you get 3 TB. How big is your swap space? ;) Sure, it's just a made-up example, but I like to nitpick and a rigorous calculation with realistic estimates would be more convincing I think.

Comment: But 3TB is a huge swap space today. I'm not rich enough to buy a 3Tb SSD, or even enough 10KRPM hard disks (you always want *fast* swap!) to make a 3TB swap. Notice that I spoke of Gigabytes sized swaps, not Terbytes ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be meaningful for tools with a short lifetime, such as command line utilities like `ls`.

For example, [Busybox](http://busybox.net/) even have a configuration option which controls whether to `free` memory as usual or let OS to cleanup it automatically on exit.

> **`FEATURE_CLEAN_UP`**
>
> As a size optimization, busybox normally exits without explicitly
> freeing dynamically allocated memory or closing files. This saves
> space since the OS will clean up for us, but it can confuse debuggers
> like valgrind, which report tons of memory and resource leaks.
>
> Don't enable this unless you have a really good reason to clean
> things up manually.

Answer (score 2):

The address space may seem practically infinite, but the physical storage on any current computer definitely isn't. The OS (any OS, not just Linux) has no way to know that the application is done with a memory page, unless it is explicitly freed. Swapped-out pages still need disk space and CPU+I/O time to be processed.

From my experience, even on the very few cases where some suave marketing guy managed to sell computer systems that were way over the requirements, the available memory *still* became an issue after some time.

Besides, if you want to know what would happen if an application stopped freeing memory, just have a look at an application that is just leaking/overusing memory, rather than outright refusing to free it. For example Firefox after several hours of tab-intensive activity will soon climb to over 3GB on my 8GB system. I don't even want to imagine how high that number could go without any memory being freed at all.

Now imagine, oh, ten applications doing the same thing simultaneously - I for one, don't have 30GB of physical or virtual memory on my desktop system. And if my system is already thrashing with just a single instance of Firefox, I fear what would happen in your proposed scenario...

Comment: +1 Yes, the Firefox folks apparently have already begun to apply the logic of the asker; a big reason for my switching to Chrome many versions ago. Always ask yourself: "What if all apps did this?" It answers most questions before Stack Overflow even loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the worst thing that can happen when not `free()`ing memory is a crash, you should consider what happens when:

- You can't allocate a socket buffer and you have to start dropping packets.
- You experience performance drops (always, as you always leak) from thrashing.
- You probably can't produce debug/diagnostic logs and/or messages anymore.
- You run out of file descriptors.

The bottom line is, free your allocated memory. It'll save your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a 64 bit OS, you have an address space of virtually
>   unlimited size

The part of this you seem to miss is the `virtual` part.

First of all you are always "limited" by the actual RAM you have.

And I mean limited as follows:
In the example of 4GB you mention, if no process frees memory and continues requesting new memory, the OS will start to use the HD for swaping virtual pages.

You will have page faults and access to HD which will incur a heavy performance overhead to the process and to the whole system if this happens for all processes running (following the aproach you think is ok).
As a result, for the user to have a "usable" system, he would have to buy more and more RAM.
How do you think a user would react if you said, your system is not responsive but you just have to buy more RAM e.g. 16GB or 32GB or .....